# Ajax isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to do a request with ajax and isn't working. The controllers have the correct code, cause if i do it with ajax they are working good.

The views is this:

```js
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      listProject();
      $("#buttoncreate").click(function(e)){
        e.listUploadProject();
      });
    });
    
      var listProject = function()
      {
        $.ajax({
          type:'get',
          url:'{{ url('admin/project/listall') }}',
          success: function(data){
            $('#ajaxwindow').empty().html(data);
          }
        });
      }
      var listUploadProject = function()
     {
       $.ajax({
         type:'get',
         url:'{{ url('admin/project/create') }}',
         success: function(data){
           $('#ajaxwindow').empty().html(data);
         }
       });
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-10">
        <h3 style="letter-spacing:40px;text-align:center;color:f15d5e;">PROYECTOS</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="padding:20px;">
      <button type="button" id="buttoncreate" class="btn btn-danger">Crear Proyecto</button>
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="ajaxwindow">
    
    </div>
```

If i only have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      listProject();
    });
```

Is working good.

Where's the problem? thanks!.

EDIT:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      listProject();
      $("#buttoncreate").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.listUploadProject();
      });
    });

      var listProject = function()
      {
        $.ajax({
          type:'get',
          url:"{{ url('admin/project/listall') }}",
          success: function(data){
            $('#ajaxwindow').empty().html(data);
          }
        });
      }
      var listUploadProject = function()
     {
       $.ajax({
         type:'get',
         url:"{{ url('admin/project/create') }}",
         success: function(data){
           $('#ajaxwindow').empty().html(data);
         }
       });
     }
```

When i click to the button and he try to do the function give me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.listUploadProject is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (projects:217)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4737)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4549)
```

Maybe something wrong with the call to listUploadProject? thanks!

Comment: what error you have in your browser console? check and tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you prematurely close your quotes. Escape them using backslash (`\`)

like this:

`url: '{{url(\'admin/project/create\')}}'`

or you can mix up the quotes:

`url: "{{url('admin/project/create')}}"`

### update 1

To answer that last error:

change function to

```
$("#buttoncreate").click(function()
{
    listUploadProject();
});
```

this will run the function on click.

Comment: which line? gonna need more than that :p @LluísPuigFerrer

Comment: I put the code like you say in edit version, check bottom of question, give me 2 minuts! I will put the error too

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer so you're getting a php error and not js?? How is the scirpt being generated?

Comment: I just change the \ \ for "" and that's good. At the beginning it doesn't give me any error, only if i put the listuploadproject it doesn't work, but if i only have listproject it works. Now is getting me unexcepted token ), let's see.

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer yeah the alternative would be using double quotes to open and close and use single quotes within - I'll update answer to suggest this -

Comment: Perfect!. Now listProject is working, but if i click on button give me an error. Edit again the question..*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150279/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-thisguyhastwothumbs).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of below code:

```
$("#buttoncreate").click(function(e)){
    e.listUploadProject();
  });
```

Try this one:

```
$("#buttoncreate").click(function(e)){
    e.preventDefault();
    listUploadProject();
  });
```

There must be some error in the console on click.